# System string value in xaml as StaticResource

Tags: wpf, xaml

Right now in xaml I have sys:String values defined as follows. Is it possible to bind the values from a resource dictionary. Lets say instead of Bmp (harcoded text) I want to say {StaticResource Bmp}. The Bmp value comes from some resource. Please help.

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    <x:Array
                Type="{x:Type sys:String}"
                x:Key="ImageFormatsArray">
                <sys:String>Bmp</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Png</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Jpg</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Tif</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Gif</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Just replace the relevant `<sys:String>` entry with a `StaticResource` reference:

```
<sys:String x:Key="BitmapFormat">Bmp</sys:String>

<x:Array x:Key="ImageFormatsArray"
         Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
  <StaticResource ResourceKey="BitmapFormat" />
  <sys:String>Png</sys:String>
  <sys:String>Jpg</sys:String>
  <sys:String>Tif</sys:String>
  <sys:String>Gif</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

However, this only works as a *static resource*; you can't use a binding or a dynamic resource.  That means the resource *must* be in scope at the time the Xaml is parsed and the array is created.

You could also reference a named constant using `x:Static`:

```cs
public static class ImageFormats
{
    public const string Bitmap = "Bmp";
}
```

```xml
<x:Array x:Key="ImageFormatsArray"
         Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
  <x:Static Member="local:ImageFormats.Bitmap" />
  <!-- ... more formats -->
</x:Array>
```

Of course, if you're going to go that far, you may as well just hard-code the entire list:

```cs
public static class ImageFormats
{
    public const string Bitmap = "Bmp";
    public const string Png = "Png";
    public const string Jpeg = "Jpg";
    public const string Tiff = "Tif";
    public const string Gif = "Gif";

    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<string> AllFormats = 
        new[] { Bitmap, Png, Jpeg, Tiff, Gif };
}
```

And then use `x:Static` to access the list of formats:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:ImageFormats.AllFormats}" />
```